# how to write csv file using using python pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv

I have some data to write in a CSV file. I want to write this format [expected format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R8G8U.png)
is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Pandas has some really good [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) on how to do this, top result for "python pandas csv" for future reference. You might need to do a little bit of finessing to make sure the blank cells are coming out as you expect, but you can use the `columns` kwarg to enforce your desired ordering.